# When multiple post happens in api,shows validation error in user's email,how can i solve it?

Tags: django-rest-framework

In serializer:

```
class EventUserRegisterSerializer(ModelSerializer):
   first_name = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
   last_name = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
   email = serializers.EmailField(validators= 
   [UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())], write_only=True)
```

views:

```
  try:
        user = User.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number, 
        email=email)
        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name

  except User.DoesNotExist:

       user = 
          User.objects.create(username=username,first_name=first_name, 
          last_name=last_name, phone_number=phone_number,
                                    email=email)
```

model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, 
    default="")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, 
    default="")
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, 
    default="")
    timestamp = UnixDateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    @property
    def unique_id(self):
         return self.first_name + self.timestamp
```

I have a partial payment system so i have to done multiple 'post' ,but validation error occurs

Comment: Can you add model details. And some more details like error details

Comment: yes added the model detail

Comment: Add error trace. I can't find where this error occurred. Because there different fields using validators. So add error trace.